# Invert fn key in Toshiba Satellite?

Tags: keyboard, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

I have a Toshiba Satellite S55-B5280. On the <kbd>F*</kbd> keys are also functions like play, pause, volume, brightness, etc, with an <kbd>FN</kbd> key to choose between <kbd>F*</kbd> or the multimedia keys.

After upgrading from Wiley to Xenial, the behavior of <kbd>FN</kbd> has changed.

Prior to upgrading, on first startup, multimedia keys would apply by default and <kbd>F*</kbd> keys would apply with <kbd>FN</kbd> pressed. After once suspending (with `pm-suspend` or closing the lid), the behavior would be reversed, and remain that way until shut down. This latter behavior was the one I wanted, and so I was in the habit of once suspending after each shutdown in order to get it.

After upgrading, the start-up behavior, with multimedia keys applying when <kbd>FN</kbd> is not pressed, persists always. I would like to invert this behavior.

The BIOS does not seem to have an option to change this behavior. Because it was affected by an upgrade, I suspect that it can be changed from within Ubuntu, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: You can look at the log files before the upgrade for clues as to ACPI programs that were being run during resume prior to upgrade. Although I'm not sure if the multimedia keys were broken after suspend and that is what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution you can use if you have dual-boot with Windows on this laptop:

Boot into Windows and use **Toshiba System Settings**. Go to **Keyboard** and change the settings for **Function Keys**.

When you reboot into Ubuntu, the setting will be carried over.

(As described in [a Toshiba forum post](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Windows-10/Windows-10-FN-keys-reversed-after-talkting-to-Windows-Tech/td-p/667069)).