# How to swap FN key fuction on Toshiba Satellite S55 A5295

Tags: keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop Toshiba S55 A5295. I want to "lock" the <kbd>FN</kbd> key function so I can access the media, brightness, and volume buttons directly without having to press the<kbd>FN</kbd> key each time. As you can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7sFD.jpg), those are the most important and prominent functions of those keys.

There is no option on the BIOS to do that but I just recently migrated from Windows and there I had the option (using Toshiba software) to swap that fuction. For example I also have a Logitech K800 and using Solaar there is an option to swap the fuction of those keys on that keyboard.

Is there something similar that I can do to do that?

Comment: Does going to keyboard settings and changing the model to Toshiba make a difference?

Comment: @xiota No, I tried that but it didn't work. The is only one Toshiba model avilable and it is a totally different one.

Comment: Apparently, on [some keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/q/88063/567307), Fn+Esc toggles the behavior you want.

Comment: @xiota Thank you. I forgot to mention that I tried that also but it didn't work. It apparently works on some brands but not Toshiba.

Comment: Does this work -- [Invert fn key in Toshiba Satellite?](https://askubuntu.com/a/832580/567307)

Comment: @xiota Thanks, I'll try. I don't have Windows installed right now but I suppose I will have to temporarily install it. I installed Ubuntu over the original WIndows 8.1 installation and on Windows I had the FN key swapped but I'll give it a try.